# Java Web Application not working on windows 7

Tags: java, oracle, jinitiator

I have a java web application installed on a server which is accessed via intranet. It worked well when i run it on a client pc with Windows XP  and IE 6, with Jinitiator. The problem comes when i run it on Windows 7, on any updated browser. The IE in Windows 7 stops responding whenever i enter the particular url for my application.

I tried to run it on other browsers like Mozilla and Netscape but they give me the plugin error for Jinitiator. In fact i downloaded the plugin and installed it for for both the browsers but still the browser cant find any plugin.

When i researched about it i found that the Jinitiator is only compatible for windows not higher than Windows xp and Browser only IE6 not higher.

I am confused about whether it is ony the JVM version problem or i have to get into the code of the application. Till now i have no access to the code of the application.It was developed by some other company in 2006 which is petty much dead by now. Can any body suggest me any solutions on what can i do to solve this compatibility problem. How can go by it and from where i should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange the JInitiator with Suns/Oracles Java Plugin. If you have access to metalink have a look there.

You find some outdated information at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/clientsod-forms10g-094744.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/readme-101362.html

If you have no idea of the topic try to get help from Oracle or one of there business partners. You probably have to update environment for getting support for newer versions.